# This toy is squeezy

Tags: grammar

I am looking for a word that expresses a feeling of sqeeze. When you have a tiny fluppy stuffed animal your hand sized, you play in your hand and squeeze it. The animal is squeezy is what I have come up, but you have no word "squeezy". What would be appropriate to replace it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do have the word [squeezy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/squeezy) but it's mostly used for plastic bottles that you squeeze to get the contents out.

I would call a stuffed toy 'squishy'.

Comment: Thank you, but according to a dictionary 'squishy' means something wet and soft. I've heard banana peels are squishy. But I am not sure If I can extend that meaning to a soft, dry, fluffy toy?

Comment: @JoeKim - Yes, you can. _Squishy_ doesn't **always** mean wet like a banana peel. Wordnet defines squishy as "easily squashed; resembling a sponge in having soft porous texture and compressibility." Also, toys like [these](http://squishiesrule.com/images/480_deluxe_squishy_package.jpg) are sometimes call "squish toys."

Comment: Thank you, J.R. How about dough? Would you say this is squish or you have some other name?

Comment: 'Dough' is not *squishy*; it is *doughy*, although @J.R. may have another word. But we wouldn't use *doughy* for a plush toy or a squish toy.

Answer (score 1):

If by *fluppy* you mean a *[plush toy](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuffed_toy)* or *flush animal*, you can just call it [fluffy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fluffy). Everyone knows that a fluffy is *squeezable*.

Comment: Thank you, but I am sure fluffy could be equivalent to squeezing

Comment: I said it is **squeezable**. You can also say *squeezably soft*, but that is a bit [old](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoHhzyh9kCg).